# Email class fails to trigger email

Tags: apex, pdf, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage, send-email

I have below email class that fails to trigger the email class. I am not getting the reason in debug log even. Can someone let me know where I am making the mistake?

**Apex class method**

```
public pageReference  generateBulkBlankform() {
       formTransactions = new List<Sample_Order_Form_abv__c>();
       for(Sample_Order_Form_abv__c sof : [SELECT Address_Line_2_abv__c, Address_Line_1_abv__c, Address_abv__c, Account_Name_abv__c, Account_abv__c, Campaign__c, Campaign_Id__c, Campaign_Name__c, 
                                              Choose_Template_abv__c, City_abv__c, City_State_Zip_abv__c, Country_abv__c,  CreatedDate, Credentials_abv__c, Dosage_Strength_abv__c, Established_Name_abv__c, 
                                              External_Id__c, Form_Created_Date_abv__c, Form_Created_DateTime_abv__c, Form_Expiration_Date_abv__c, Form_Expiry_Date_abv__c, Form_Fulfillment_Status_abv__c, Form_ID_abv__c, 
                                              Form_Status_abv__c, Form_template_abv__c, Form_Template_Name_abv__c, Id,LastModifiedDate, License_abv__c, License_Expiration_Date_abv__c, License_Status_abv__c,
                                               Name, NDC_abv__c, OwnerId, Product_abv__c, Proprietary_Name_abv__c, Quantity_abv__c, RecordTypeId, Role_abv__c, Sample_Form_Allocation_abv__c, Sample_Name_abv__c, 
                                               Sample_Order_Campaign_abv__c, State_abv__c, SystemModstamp, Territory_abv__c, Vendor_Tracking_Number_abv__c, Zip_abv__c FROM Sample_Order_Form_abv__c where Account_abv__c = null limit 1])
       {
           formTransactions.add(sof);
          // FormIDs = FormIds.add(sof.ID);
       }
       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/FormTemplatePrinter?id=a4VM0000000HtpOMAS&param1='+formquantity);
        pageRef.setRedirect(false);
        return pageRef;
       system.debug('@@Saikat1');  


// Take the PDF content
Blob b = pageRef.getContent();


// Create the email attachment
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
        efa.setBody(b);



   List<string> addresses =  new List<string>(); 

       for (User u : [Select Email From User where Username = : UserInfo.getUserName()]) {     

            addresses.add( u.Email);


            }


            // Sets the paramaters of the email
            email.setSubject( 'Email Generated Blank Forms');
            email.setToAddresses( addresses );
            email.setPlainTextBody( 'Please find attached forms');

            email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
            system.debug('@@test'+email);
            // Sends the email

                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});

            return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on line 16:

```
return pageRef;
```

When you return from a function, nothing written after that will execute.

Try moving this line to the end of your code (and get rid of the `return null;` statement) and you should see the email being sent.